# Could opencv mix compile with Objective C for OS X app development?

Tags: macos, opencv, objective-c++

I want to use OS X default GUI like NSImageView to show an OpenCV image for an OS X app(not iOS), so I need to use Objective C with C++, it's not a big deal for Apple LLVM compiler. But when it comes to OpenCV, even just to import opencv2/opencv.hpp in to a '.mm' file will crash the build.

I got the error:"Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers" in OpenCV utility.hpp line 'bool check() const;'.

I searched for this, I have a similar question here ([Mix Objective-C and C++ and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128097/mix-objective-c-and-c-and-opencv)). This problem is with some macro defined in both Cocoa and OpenCV. The answer is to import OpenCV header before Cocoa headers in '.pch' file.

By default an iOS template has a '.pch' file but OS X template don't. So I add a '.pch' with no luck, it won't compile either.

So my question is how can I do the same thing like the iOS solution? How can I get my OS X compile with OpenCV?

Answer (score 7):

You can just import / include opencv headers directly in your source file when you need it, but make sure to do so before including Cocoa headers.

For example, I need to use OpenCV in `ViewController.h` so I did the following in `ViewController.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#endif

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

Now, here is the tricky part: you also need to be careful for files that depend on `ViewController.h`. Specifically, any other Cocoa files that import `ViewController.h` will need to import this file first thing (even before its own header, because its own header will import some Cocoa headers already).

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
#ifdef check
#define OS_X_STUPID_CHECK_MACRO check
#undef check
#endif

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

#ifdef OS_X_STUPID_CHECK_MACRO
#define check OS_X_STUPID_CHECK_MACRO
#undef OS_X_STUPID_CHECK_MACRO
#endif
```

What this does is save and undefine the offending macro before the preprocessor includes the header. Then, after the header is safely included--free of nonsense, I redefine the macro to what it was before.

Comment: Including a prefix header (.pch) should've worked. Did you make sure to set the Prefix Header build setting of your targets to reference this file?

Comment: In my case this code had to be deployed cross platform (OS X, iOS, Android, and Windows), so I found this to be the easiest solution.

Comment: sure, I understand... and, at any rate, it's rather endearing in its ad-hoc-ness...

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is to define `__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0` somewhere before everything else gets included. I put this in the Preprocessor Macros section of my Project's Build Settings.

Further explanation can be found in the `usr/include/AssertMacros.h` file:

```
For time immemorial, Mac OS X has defined version of most of these macros without the __ prefix, which
could collide with similarly named functions or macros in user code, including new functionality in
Boost and the C++ standard library.

A future release of Mac OS X will no longer do this, and will require that clients move to the
new macros as defined above.  However, in the interim both the new and old macros will work, unless
clients define a macro __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES before this file is included
in their compilations.  Clients who do not want the older macros defined can accomplish this by adding
    #define __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES 0
at the top of their sources, or my adding -D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0 to the
gcc compilation options.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it isnt the best way to solve this but I gave me root and edited the utillity.hpp from

```
bool check() const;
```

to

```
bool check(bool) const;
```

In my case everthing did work after that.