# OpenCV in Cocoa application (OS X App)

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, opencv

I have installed OpenCV3.0 via homebrew successfully.

[image]

And then I create a new "command line tool" project in XCode,Which works fine with OpenCV included.

Then I create a "Cocoa Application" project, take following steps to include OpenCV:

1: "Header Search Paths" being set to `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_1/include`

2: "Library Search Paths" being set to `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_1/lib`

3: "Other Linker Flags" being set to

```
-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab
```

4: In .mm file

[image]

After these steps, I try to compile my project,error shows up like this:

[image]

How can I fix this? What should I do to make OpenCV usable in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#ifdef check
#define OS_X_STUPID_CHECK_MACRO check
#undef check
#endif

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#ifdef OS_X_STUPID_CHECK_MACRO
#define check OS_X_STUPID_CHECK_MACRO
#undef OS_X_STUPID_CHECK_MACRO
#endif
```

I've got solution from this [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903319/could-opencv-mix-compile-with-objective-c-for-os-x-app-development) post.